# Firebase test lab never start

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I have setup a project in Firebase to run Instrumented Test for my app. I created the project from Android Studio, then I went to the Firebase Console and moved the project to Blaze Plan. I logged in and setup the project in Android Studio, so far so good, the thing is that when I try to run the test in Firebase using the Sample Spark Configuration but Android Studio never finishes to upload the APK, I don't have any error neither, what I get in Android Studio RUN console are the following lines:

```
Testing started at 11:29 ...  
Using Cloud Storage Bucket location test-bucket-id 
Uploading app APK ...
```

So, it seems there are some issue witht the bucket or with the project, but I'm not able to read any error anywhere. So, where can I access any log to know what is going on? Does a firebase project expose logs though its web UI or does Android Studio allows me to get some kind of logs besides what I get on the build window?

Comment: I think you should contact Firebase support about this.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Turned out there wasn't anything wrong with the project or the bucket. All I had to do was specify the package of my instrumented tests instead of using the "all in module" option in the run configuration.